# Would it make sense to replace Julia|R|Python executables with a nice "prefix" in a server?

Tags: resources, nice

I manage a computational server in my lab (single CPU), where users script and run programs in R|Python|Julia using a variety of interfaces (RStudio server, JupyterHub/VsCode, command line..)

To be sure that their load doesn't influence system programs and that each one doesn't block all the work of the others, would be useful to wrap e.g. `julia` with `nice -n 10 juliaorig`, and the same for `R` and `Python`, or would it be useless ?

EDIT: What would be the optimal for me would be to allocate resourses equally between users (rather than processes), e.g. user A with 12 running threads receives the same CPU time than user B with 6 threads and user C that is running a single thread...
A second best would be to limit the number of cores by user, or "trick" the OS to communicate this (lower) number of cores to the apps that ask the number of cores available. This would have the advantage that a user could still manually set the number of threads of his script to higher levels if he really needs them.

Answer (score 2):

`nice` is relative priority. Changing it only makes sense if some programs are supposed to have higher priority than others.

But if *all* user programs are reniced to the same 10, the end result is that all users are the same priority again, just as before (when all of them were equally at 20). The only thing you've achieved is make all users equally lower priority than system services and misc tools (which are still at 20), so now your `apt upgrade` overwhelms everyone's work.

(Most system services don't need higher priority than users. For the few which do, raise the service's priority instead of lowering users.)

With equal priority, be it 10 or 20, one user program *already* should not block others. The kernel's process scheduler should divide CPU time more or less fairly, the same for disk I/O. The only issue is that a user with more processes will get accordingly more CPU time than one with few, but that's probably not something you can solve with your suggestion.

As far as I know, putting each user's processes in a separate *cgroup* will balance the resources at cgroup level. This is usually the default on systemd-based systems, although you might still need to enable CPU accounting and set CPU weights for `user-.slice`. (All settings that you do through `user-.slice.d/*.conf` (yes, `-.`) will be inherited by every `user-XXX.slice` cgroup.)

- cks: [The basics of Linux fair share CPU scheduling in cgroup v2 ('unified cgroups')](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/CgroupV2FairShareScheduling)
- cks: [How I think you set up fair share scheduling under systemd](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/SystemdFairshareScheduling)
- systemd manual: [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html)
- Red Hat: [How to manage cgroups with CPUShares](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/cgroups-part-two)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428317/where-are-systemds-configurations-for-cgroups
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732408/configure-cgroups-v2-for-fair-resources-sharing-between-users

(Cgroups are more commonly used with containers; you might also find resources talking about per-container fair CPU sharing, which should apply the same way to per-user.)

---

"Single CPU" is fine as long as it's multi-core; each core is almost a separate CPU. But if it's single-core as well, it would be time to upgrade. (Is it a VM or is it a Pentium 3?)

Comment: It's a 12 cores soon to be upgraded to 32 cores.. I understood that all processes (and threads) are run with the same priority, but I would like to have the same priority at the user level, e.g. the 12 threads of user A receive the same CPU time of the 2 threads of user B...

Comment: One 12-core CPU works pretty much the same way as 12 CPUs. As for user-level priority, that's where cgroups come in. I'll try to add more in the post.